# header usando endereço relativo e " ../ " não funciona

Tags: php

Como faço um header para uma pagina que esta um nível acima, ex: Tenho a seguinte arvore de diretorios, desejo fazer um header do validarLogin.php para a welcomePage.php? tentei utilizar um ../ para acessar a pasta views e não funcionou

```
controller
--- validarCadastro.php
--- validarLogin.php
views
--- index.php
--- welcomePage.php
```

Código de redirecionamento:

```
$string = http_build_query($consulta);
$url = 'Location:'.'../views/welcomePage.php?'.$string;
header($url);
```

Comment: Porque você não pega de alguma forma (ou cria uma forma de pegar) a url base da sua aplicação. Isso solucionaria o problema.

Comment: como assim? estou acessano pelo localhost, o endereço completo é: `localhost/PHP/Site/modules/users/views/welcomePage.php`

Comment: Mostra o código do redirecionamento pra nós, para que possamos ajudar

Comment: Se for utilizado `'Location:'.'http://localhost/PHP/Site/modules/users/views/ewelcomePage.php?'.$string;` funciona

Comment: como é a sua estrutura? em que lugar que chama esse location? qual o arquivo? passa por uma index.php fora desses diretórios para redirecionamento??

Comment: Não passa por um index, este redirecionamento esta situado no final do validar login e independe de resultado (logado ou nao)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você estiver usando caminhos reais(ou seja se não estiver usando reescrita de urls do Apache) algo como o código a seguir poderia resolver:

```
$linkAtual = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
$string = http_build_query($consulta);
$url = 'Location: '.$linkAtual.'/../views/welcomePage.php?'.$string;
header($url);
```

`Location` costuma ser bastante rígido, perceba que você não colocou espaço entre o `:` da palavra `Location` e a `URL`, também pode ser isso que esteja atrapalhando.

Caso mesmo assim não funcione, informe mais um pouco:
 - Você recebe algum erro, se sim, então qual erro você recebe?
 - Você usa alguma plataforma ou `PHP` puro?
 - Está usando `sobre escrita` de `URLs` no `.htaccess`?

**Deixe-nos saber o que funcionou para você.**